# change size of MPMoviePlayerController view

Tags: iphone

How to change size of MPMoviePlayerController views. Now it is covering full screen in landscape mode. Can we resize to half size or other size? I want display only half screen and other video related info display in remaining screen? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can change the size of the player. Before you create the movie object, attach a selector, like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyWindowChanged:) name:UIWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification object:nil];
```

This way, when the new window of the player appears, you can grab it and change its size to fit your needs.

You can also add the Overlay:

```
\- (void) keyWindowChanged: (NSNotification *) aNot {

    if([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count] > 1)
    {
        NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
        UIWindow * tmp = [windows objectAtIndex:1];//[aNot object];
        movOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 30, 40)];
        movOverlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
        [tmp addSubview:movOverlay];
        ...
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so--it wants to take over the entire screen.

Comment: any one have any example for not covering full screen in itune or code? Plz pass to me...

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayerController take the entire screen.  The only option for is to use a 3rd party video viewer library.